# Is there any way to tell which side you'll be on (blue or purple) before the game starts?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have always wondered: is there any way of determining whether you'll be blue or purple before the game loads? Could help at chara select to plan early strategies (IE, getting golems on blue side with AD carry/support).

Answer (score 10):

Yes!

In the champion selection

[image]

If "Your team" has a blue flair, you will be the blue team (Lower left corner)

If "Your team" has a purple flair, you will be the purple team (Upper right corner)

Answer (score -1):

The blue side picks first and bans first. I don't know how to know your side - if it's at all possible - with a blind pick.

Answer (score -1):

If you are palying Blind Pick, there is no way of telling who is where.

In Draft Pick, First Pick and First Bann show who is Blue Side. So if your team has First Bann/Pick, your team is blue side (bottom left), if the enemy team has it, your team is purple (top right)